# how compute sum of value for a field using intervals of different field in solr?

Tags: java, apache, solr, solrj

I have multiple solr documents in the following form

> { requests : [23], timestamp : [1562146437780] }

**i have to get sum of requests in intervals of timestamp.**

I tried using facets but couldn't figure out how to use on two fields

i did try this. but was giving me count of documents in the timestamp interval.

```
 query.addNumericRangeFacet(TIMESTAMP, startTime, endTime, gap);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to generate the sum for multiple ranges, or just for one specific range given as `startTime`, `endTime`?

Comment: from 'startTime' to 'endTime' with an interval of 'gap'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this by using [the JSON facet API for range facets](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/json-facet-api.html#range-facet). These will allow you to give a sub facet that works with the domain (i.e. the documents in the bucket) from the facet above.

You start by creating a range facet:

```
RangeFacetMap rangeFacet = new RangeFacetMap(TIMESTAMP, startTime, endTime, gap);
```

Then you add a sub facet that invokes a sum:

```
rangeFacet.withStatSubFacet("requests_sum", "sum(requests)")
```

You send this request to Solr by using:

```
final JsonQueryRequest request = new JsonQueryRequest()
    .setQuery("*:*")
    .withFacet("timestamps", rangeFacet);
QueryResponse queryResponse = request.process(solrClient, COLLECTION_NAME);
```

I don't have an instance or documents to test with right now, but this is built from the information under [Nester Facet Example](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/json-facet-api.html#nested-facet-example) in the reference guide.

Comment: Can i use SolrQuery and make this same request?

Comment: Getting exception **org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/Requests: can not use FieldCache on multivalued field: requests**

Comment: Yes, you're going to have to make that field singlevalued. Are you using it in a multivalued fashion? Doesn't seem like that from your post above.

Comment: it will be a multivalued field

Comment: Index the sum of the field's values to a single field, then use that for summing up the requests.